# Mean value for nested list with variable length

Tags: python, numpy

I have a list of lists with variable length, something like:

```
a = [[0,0,10,10],[10,20,5,10,6],[5,10,2]]
```

I tried to get the average of each list like that:

```
np.mean(a, axis=1)
```

But I got this error:

```
IndexError: tuple index out of range
```

I don't really understand what is the Problem but I think it is due to variable length. Is there an easy way to solve it without calculating the mean value in a loop for each list?

Comment: Have you noticed that the last element in `a` is just 3-items long while the other two elements are 4-items long??

Comment: yes I know that but only 1st element has 4 elemnts, the second has 5 elements

Comment: No, you have to apply the `mean` to each list.  `np.mean` works on a multidimensional list.  `np.array(a)` produces an object dtype array containing the lists.  Look at if it that isn't clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `map` function:

```py
>>> list(map(np.mean, a))
[5, 10.2, 5.666666666666667]
```

Comment: This is a loop on each list, just different syntax.

Comment: I wasn't familiar with map but after reading your comment I read About map and found out that it's a loop but in different syntax as you mentioned. At least with map I can get the mean in one line code.